# Gerar entidade utilizando uma determinada conexão

Tags: php, symfony-2, doctrine-2

Considere o seguinte ficheiro de configuração:

config.yml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: slqX45
        connections:
            slqX44:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
            slqX45:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     "%database_host_co%"
                port:     "%database_port_co%"
                dbname:   "%database_name_co%"
                user:     "%database_user_co%"
                password: "%database_password_co%"
                charset:  UTF8
```

Repare que a conexão marcada como default é a `sqlX45`.

Entretanto tenho algumas entidades que possuam as suas respectivas tabelas na base de dados `A` e outras na base de dados `B`, por isso a necessidade de utilizar 2 conexões.

Ao executar os seguintes comandos na console, preciso indicar qual conexão deve ser utilizada e qual a respectiva entidade, por exemplo:

```
app/console doctrine:generate:entities --entidade="EntidadeA" --conexao="slqX44" 
app/console doctrine:schema:update --entidade="EntidadeA" --conexao="slqX44"
```

Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você cria configurações de conexões do Doctrine dentro de um projeto Symfony, é possível determinar diferentes *entity managers* para cada conexão. Para cada *entity manager*, é possível discriminar as entidades (e, consequentemente, tabelas) serão gerenciados.

Dê uma olhada na [configuração do Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html).

Portanto, acredito que sua configuração ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: slqX45
        connections:
            slqX44:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
            slqX45:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     "%database_host_co%"
                port:     "%database_port_co%"
                dbname:   "%database_name_co%"
                user:     "%database_user_co%"
                password: "%database_password_co%"
                charset:  UTF8
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            em_sqlX44:
                connection: slqX44
                mappings: ~ # os mapeamentos que o EM em_sqlX44 gerenciará
            em_sqlX45:
                connection: slqX45
                mappings: ~ # os mapeamentos que o EM em_sqlX45 gerenciará
```

Depois disso, basta dar uma olhada nos argumentos aceitos por cada um dos comandos. Em geral, eles aceitam que você especifique em qual *entity manager* aquele comando rodará – logo, com quais entidades o comando irá trabalhar.

O argumento que os comandos usam é `--entity-manager=(seu entity manager)`.

Comment: Obrigado pelo seu tempo. Entretanto vi a documentação mas não encontro maneira de configurar em qual "entity manager" cada entidade estará. Só encontrei maneira de indicar no "mappings" qual o bundle e no meu caso as 2 entidade pertencem ao mesmo, porém em diferentes base de dados.

Comment: Você pode dizer quais entidades farão parte de cada entity manager, mesmo que estejam no mesmo bundle. Veja a solução dessa pergunta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311485/working-with-two-entity-managers-in-the-same-bundle-in-symfony2